# How to open a file directly in browser without download in React with the file name

Tags: reactjs, file

Is there any way to open a file directly in browser instead of downloading it with the file name as it is?

window.open() -> opens file directly but it opens the file with a random numbered file name instead of the original file name.

Note  : I know that download functionality can retain the original file name. But I need the same to work when the file directly opens without download.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
 let newWindow = window.open('https://www.myetherwallet.com/img/big-spaceman.e9a9582b.png')

    setTimeout(function () {
      newWindow.document.title = "Spaceman";
    }, 100);
  }
```